# Xamarin - Shell Navigatin not working from Service

Tags: c#, shell, xamarin, navigation

I have a Xamarin Forms project and what I want to achieve is when I get a 401 response code go to my `LoginPage` as the token will be no longer valid.

I have a `Logout` method in which I call the GoToAsync method but it returns an error and I don't know why.

Error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

I have a Service class called `AzureApiService` in which I have this generic get method. When the response is not successful I want it to go to the login page.

```
        // Generic Get Method
        public async Task<T> HttpGetAsync<T>(string url, string token)
        {
            T result = default(T);

            try
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
                HttpContent content = response.Content;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var jsonResponse = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResponse);
                }
                else
                {
                    await Logout();
                    //throw new Exception(((int)response.StatusCode).ToString() + " - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnError(ex.ToString());
            }

            return result;

        }
```

This is my `Logout` method

```
 private async Task Logout()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"login");

            //if (!CurrentPropertiesService.GetCart().Equals(""))
            //{
            //    CurrentPropertiesService.RemoveCart();
            //}
            //CurrentPropertiesService.Logout();
        }
```

This is what I have on my `LoginPage`

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        private static string token;
        private AzureApiService _azureApiService;

        public LoginPage()
        {
            _azureApiService = new AzureApiService();
            InitializeComponent();
            go();

        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            !_azureApiService.IsExpired(CurrentPropertiesService.GetToken())
            if (CurrentPropertiesService.IsAuth())
            {
                var hola = CurrentPropertiesService.GetToken();
                if (!_azureApiService.IsExpired(hola))
                {
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//main");
                }

            }
        }
```

And here is my `AppShell` with my Shell routing

```
<!--As it calls before TabBar it will skip over displaying anything else-->
    <ShellItem Route="login">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}"/>
    </ShellItem>

    <TabBar Route="main">
        <Tab Title="Explorar" Icon="tab_feed.png">
            <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:CategoryPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Route="CartPage" Title="Carrito" Icon="tab_feed.png">
            <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:CartPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Route="InvoicePage" Title="Factura" Icon="tab_feed.png">
            <ShellContent  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:InvoicePage}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
```

Here are the routes I have registered

```
public AppShell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Routing.RegisterRoute("login", typeof(LoginPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(CategoryPage), typeof(CategoryPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(CartPage), typeof(CartPage));
            Routing.RegisterRoute("InvoicePage", typeof(InvoicePage));
        }
```

If I use this route it will just do nothing and then continue with the code on my `HttpGetAsync` method and I don't want it to

`await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//login");`

The route that works it's "login" and then gives null error after `LoginPage` constructor.

`await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"login");`

So what I want to achieve is going to the login page when I'm on the main page. I have been able to achieve that so far from the ViewModels but from my `AzureApiService` it doesn't work. Why is this happening? Please help and thanks.

**EDIT**

With a breakpoint I have seen that it goes from this line

`await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"login");`

to the `LoginPage` constructor then to that line again and the constructor again and when it gets back the third time to that line it will give the `NullReferenceException`. I have no idea why this is happening

So here is what happens when I use the route //login which is the correct one. It goes on with the code.

[Debugging video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OY59eTOmnrRA_8YMcnsg3i7MARzl37dA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your first step is to determine what is null, then work from there. Set a breakpoint and step through it

Comment: @Andrew I have done that and it simply stops after LoginPage() constructor and gives null

Comment: I tried your route, but I can't reproduce your problem. And if I pass the wrong route path `GoToAsync` method, it will throw null exception. but both `login` and `\\login` are correct on above, beacause you declar login route in the xaml and register it in the [code behind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#register-routes).

Comment: And if you have register the login in the xaml, and you have no need to call RegisterRoute method to make the login page as gloabl route again. For xaml route `\\login` is correct value.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT The problem is not the route, the issue is that the program will continue after that line

Comment: Can you try remove `login`  from gloabl root and just use  login xaml route for testing ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I tried that already and still didn't work. The program continues with the code and because of that I get errors. I have found a workaround for what I wanted to achieve as I have not been able to do it this way. I have seen a similar question to mine and I found that that person couldn't do it either. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Good, could mind share it below if you have found solution?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT It is a workaround for what I wanted which was cheching if the token is edxpired then logout. I did that at the start of my application and removed all the code that I was trying to implement in this question. Because of that I don't consider it a solution to the problem itself of being able to navigate from the Service without issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try run it from application main thread like

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
   await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(SomePage)}");
});
```